# Pure javascript FormData upload with file and data fails on PHP side

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a typical file upload form:

```
<form id="attachform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/app/upload.php" method="POST" target="attachments">
        <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
        <input type="hidden" name="func" value="addattach" />
        <input type="hidden" name="relnum" value="{$relnum}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="75000" />
        <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
        Select file: <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" /><br/>
        Add a file name: <input type="text" id="filename" name="filename" />
    </form>
    <input type="button" id="uploadbutton" value="Attach File" onclick="addAttachment('/app/upload.php','attachform','{$relnum}','userfile','filename','uploadbutton','attachments');" />
```

and I'm using pure javascript ajax, not jQuery:
This is the full javascript function

```
function addAttachment(APPPATH,theform,relnum,filebox,filename,thebutton,thetarget){
var f = document.getElementById(filename);
var fb = document.getElementById(filebox);
var tb = document.getElementById(thebutton);
var t = document.getElementById(thetarget);
var fm = document.getElementById(theform);
///*
if(fm){
    tb.value = "Uploading...";

    var fdata = new FormData(fm);
    var xFile = new ReportXRequest(APPPATH, fdata, t, "att");
    if(xFile)
        xFile.sendRequest("multipart/form-data");

}
```

}

The ReportXRequest is my ajax object that works with my entire web site. I built it before jQuery existed.

Here is my request object:

```
function ReportXRequest(theurl, theparams, thetarget, theoption, /* optional */ thedataform, thefocusitem){

var url = theurl;
var req = null;
var params = theparams;
var target = thetarget;
var myoption = theoption;
var dataform;  // = thedataform;
var focusitem;

dataform = thedataform || null;
focusitem = thefocusitem || null;

this.onReadyStateChange = function(){
    if(req.readyState == 4){
        if(req.status == 200){
            try{
                var response = req.responseText;

                switch(myoption){


                    case 'att':
                        var ans = response.split("=");
                        if(ans[1] == "ERROR"){
                            target = document.getElementById('actionnotice');
                            target.innerHTML = ans[0];
                            setTimeout("clearActionnotice()", 3500);
                            break;
                        }
                        target.innerHTML = response;
                        var f = document.getElementById(dataform);
                        if(f) {f.reset();}
                        if(focusitem){
                            var fi = document.getElementById(focusitem);
                            if(fi)
                                fi.focus();
                        }
                        break;


                }

            }
                catch(e){
                    alert("Error retrieving report data:\n" + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}

this.sendRequest = function(contenttype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"){
    req = this.getHttpRequestObject();
    if(!req){
        alert("Cannot instantiate request object!");
        return false;
    }
    req.onreadystatechange = this.onReadyStateChange;   
    req.open("POST",url,true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",contenttype);
    req.send(params);
    return true;
}
this.getHttpRequestObject = function(){
    var txhp;
    try
    {
        txhp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        try
        {
            txhp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
        }
        catch(e2)
        {
            try
            {
                txhp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e3)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return txhp;
}
```

}

On the server, I am unable to read and utilize `$_REQUEST`, `$_POST` and `$_FILES`.
`$_FILES` is empty.  The other two are populated, but I am unable to extract the data using the arrays as I normally do:

```
$value = $_POST['indexname'];
```

What I get with a var_dump of `$_REQUEST`, `$_POST` is the following:

The request array:

```
array(23) { ["-----------------------------15853197524937 Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"]=> string(1010) ""func" addattach -----------------------------15853197524937 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="relnum" 18 -----------------------------15853197524937 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" 75000 -----------------------------15853197524937 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="Mamaroneck_Lady.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg "image file" -----------------------------15853197524937 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename" ML -----------------------------15853197524937-- " ["sid"]=> string(32) "f4f4aeaf385575530e406621301ff2d6" ["perm"]=> string(8) "44444444" ["folder"]=> string(12) "deltatesting" ["tid"]=> string(1) "1" ["uid"]=> string(2) "19" ["clid"]=> string(4) "1054" ["prid"]=> string(1) "1" ["rpid"]=> string(1) "1" }

The post array:

array(15) { ["-----------------------------15853197524937 Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"]=> string(1010) ""func" addattach -----------------------------15853197524937 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="relnum" 18 -----------------------------15853197524937 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" 75000 -----------------------------15853197524937 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="Mamaroneck_Lady.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg "image file" -----------------------------15853197524937 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename" ML -----------------------------15853197524937-- " }
```

I replaced the actual image file with the quote "image file".

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: "The ReportXRequest is my ajax object that works with my entire web site. I built it before jQuery existed." — And it looks like it can't handle `FormData` objects, but you didn't include its code. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "What I get with a var_dump" — A var_dump of what, precisely?

Comment: `document.getElementById(theform);`, I'm guessing that `theform` contains  the form id? The code you have posted isn't nearly close to enough for us to see what's going on and be able to help you. Post _all_ relevant code.

Comment: It says what the var_dump is: the request array and the post array.

Comment: @Quentin I added all the relevant code.
What I noticed is the request object was defaulting to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as the content-type, so I passed "multipart/form-data" in the call to sendrequest.  It didn't help.  It actually made it worse because the image file didn't even reach my php file.

With "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" the image is in the $_POST array, but unreachable.  With "multipart/form-data" it's nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content type needs to be multipart/form-data **and specify the boundary** as a parameter to it.

You don't know what the boundary will be, so you need to **not specify the content-type header**.

The browser will generate the correct one for you when you pass a FormData object to XHR's `send` method.

Comment: You, sir, are amazing!  Thank you so, so much!